# Authenticate to Dynamics 365 for Mobile App without Registering App in AD

Tags: dynamics-365, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I was doing some research on authenticating to Dynamics 365 through the Web API and everything I come across says that you have to register your app in AD to get a client id.  If I wanted to publish an app to the app store or google play store for multiple dynamics 365 users to use across many different organizations, how would that be accomplished?  Would users have to get their admins to register the app in AD before they could use it?  I'm confused as to how to create an app for dynamics for general distribution.  A point in the right direction would be much appreciated or if it's not possible, that's fine too....pulling my hair out searching!

Comment: I'd suggest getting in touch with MS Partner support, they will help with this kind of issue.